# Why the toURI() method is giving me the erro "Method invocation 'toURI' may produce 'NullPointerException'"?

Tags: java, runtime-error

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path).toURI()));
```

When executing the program the contnent in the file, which is an xml file, is shown as doc:  "[#document: null]"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this due to the implementation details from[`CLass::getClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--):

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

So in some situations calling `new File().getClassLoader().getResource()` will cause a `NullPointerException`. The warning isn't quite as clear as I'd like it to be but this isn't an issue with `toURI`.

To be safe you should check if `getClassLoader()` returns null, and then access the bootstrap classloader with [`ClassLoader::getSystemClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--):

```java
ClassLoader loader = File.class.getClassLoader();

if (loader == null) {
    loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
}

Document doc = builder.parse(loader.getResource(path));
```

Comment: I get errors with `(load == null)` and with `loader.getResource(path)` because it can't resolve the method parse

Comment: oops I had a typo `loader == null` will update. I don't know what library you are working with so I won't be of much use for the `DocumentBuilder::parse` error